# LINQ-to-Entities Array.Contains doesn't obey collation

Tags: c#, linq, linq-to-entities, azure-sql-database, collation

I have a case-insensitive and accent-insensitive collation on an SQL Azure column. For example, I have these fields:

`sample`,
`şAmple`,
`SAMPLE`.

In SQL Server Management Studio if I query `where field = 'Sample'`, I get all the fields. In Entity Framework, I have an array of tokens, for example:

`var array = new string[]{ "sampLe", "somethingelse", "anotherhing"] };`

I am trying to search my database for any fields that match the items in this array. Array is not a big array, it usually consists of just one item, and in worst case five items. I am using:

`var existingTags = await db.Tags.Where(x => array.Contains(x.Tag)).ToListAsync();`

I expect this query to return all the "samples" from the database, but it doesn't match. Why?

Comment: What version of EF are you using? Could you post the SQL that gets generated for the query?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As I've further investigated the issue, it's not an EF issue, the returned results were actually correct, it turned out to be an issue with my own programming.